# Subdomain vs application for MsDeploy

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am facing config collision issue when deployed application to siteroot/child. While I fix & diagnose the issue. I read on that: subdomain is treated as different site altogether - the cost I would pay is DNS configuration.

But before I configure my DNS & wait too long for changes to propagate, I would need a bit of confidence from community:

The question is: If I create a subdomain `child.siteroot.com` & point it to `siteroot.com/child` 
**child** would not inherit config sections from siteroot.com right?

P.S. I am using Windows/IIs environment.

I have already referred [SO community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965609/subdomain-vs-subdirectory-in-web-programming) but they talk about pros & cons in general. My question is more specific to Web.Config inheritence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, configuration inheritance only works within a site. Since your subdomain would be different IIS Website, your root web.config will not be used for inheritance.