# What's the difference of using subdomain vs path to file?

Tags: subdomain, filepath

Why do some website uses subdomain instead of path file?

Let's take for example the google. They have `translate.google.com`, and not `www.google.com/translate.html`?

While when you search for google map, the resulted url is `maps.google.com/` but when you clicked that url, it will redirect you to `www.google.com/maps/`

What's the difference of using these two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subdomain vs. subdirectory in web programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965609/subdomain-vs-subdirectory-in-web-programming)

Comment: I didn't see that coming. Thanks for the link. =)